# Ruby and Metaprogramming and Modules

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

i have a question about how to include Modules and execute there methods on runtime. I read about Metaprogramming and I guess I got the basic point, but I do not understand how to use this in my specific case.

For example:
I would like to generate text based on blocks in two different ways

```
class TextGenerator

def create_text
 if condition
  create_full_text
 else
  create_short_text
 end
end

private

def create_full_text
 intro
 middle
 ending
end

def create_short_text
 middle
end

def intro
 "intro"
end

def middle
 "middle"
end

def ending
 "ending"
end

end
```

What I would like to achieve is, I would like to extract the functionality of the methods *create_full_text* and *create_short_text* to dedicated modules and include the module if the condition matches. The text creation will happen via call *create_text* from the included module.

Is my question understandable and also makes the idea sense?
Maybe someone can push me i a correct direction.

---

Based on Sergios answer is there also a way of extending in a dynamic way.

Instead of:

```
if condition
 generator.extend(WithFullText)
else
 generator.extend(WithShortText)
end
```

it would be great to have something like (very basic broad example):

```
@MODULES = {
 full: "WithFullText",
 short: "WithShortText"
}

def create_text_by_type(type)
 module_name = @MODULES[type]
 #no idea how this can work
 module_class = getModuleByName(module_name)
 generator.extend(module_class)
 generator.create_text
end
```

---

Best Alex

Comment: While technically achievable, dynamic runtime instance patching is rarely a good idea. Is there a purpose you want to achieve? Or is it just a throw-away exercise?

Comment: This edit is what I meant by "it should be asked as another question". I nudged you in the right direction, right? So the original question is answered. Mutating questions like this is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe someone can push me i a correct direction

Sure. You can dynamically add methods from modules using `extend`, for example.

```
module WithFullText
  def create_full_text
    "full text"
  end
end

class TextGenerator
end

generator = TextGenerator.new
generator.create_full_text # ~> -:5:in `<main>': undefined method `create_full_text' for #<TextGenerator:0x007ffb818b1990> (NoMethodError)
generator.extend(WithFullText)
generator.create_full_text # => "full text"
```

Although normally, people just include *both* methods and then call one of them.

```
class TextGenerator
  include MyTextMethods
end
```

You need a very good reason *not* to do that (because it means more complicated code/flow).

Comment: Thanks Sergio,
This looks like, it could work for me. Practically, there will be more and more modules, which will create the text in its own way, and I do not want to have include all available modules. I also added a follow up below

Comment: @AlexBug: but why not include all available modules?

Comment: "@SergioTulentsev" is it not  class overloading adding x amounts modules instead only one, which is needed

Comment: @AlexBug: "too much functionality" is a legit problem, yes, BUT this dynamic extension is not an answer. It only makes things worse. It doesn't remove any of the existing cognitive load and adds its own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need here is the strategy design pattern. There are better ways to implement it than using `include`. Also metaprogramming is a powerful tool, but many times the code is more readable and easier to understand by using a simple `case` rather than some magical method generation on the fly or using the `send` method.
How about something like this:

```
module TextGenerator
  class FullText
    def self.generate
      "full text"
    end
  end

  class ShortText
    def self.generate
      "short text"
    end
  end
end


module ChooseTextGeneratorStrategy
  def self.included klass
    klass.singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :create_text_type)
  end

  def create_text
    case self.class.create_text_type
    when :short
      TextGenerator::ShortText.generate
    when :full
      TextGenerator::FullText.generate
    end
  end
end


class ClassNeedsFullText
  include ChooseTextGeneratorStrategy
  @create_text_type = :full
end

class ClassNeedsShortText
  include ChooseTextGeneratorStrategy
  @create_text_type = :short
end

p ClassNeedsFullText.new.create_text  # "full text"
p ClassNeedsShortText.new.create_text # "short text"
```

The naming is maybe not the best, but you can get the point. If you need the context of `ClassNeedsFullText` you can simple pass it through a parameter: `TextGenerator::FullText.generate self`.
The `@create_text_type` is just an example. You can simplify it even more by using a helper method:

```
def act_like_create_text type
  include ChooseTextGeneratorStrategy

  @create_text_type = type
end

class ClassNeedsShortText
  act_like_create_text :short
end

p ClassNeedsShortText.new.create_text # "short text"
```

Comment: This. Proper OOP is the way to go here. (if I understand their problem correctly). Strategies and focused single-purpose classes.

Comment: Your implementation is overly complicated, though. You don't need _any_ of that class-level logic, since the strategy is resolved at instance level. Maybe as simple as [this](https://pastebin.com/7axUVJYd)?

Comment: Yes I know, it is for showing what is possible. On the other hand using only one line `act_like_create_text :short` is very neat if they have many classes ;-) The rest depends on how they wanna chose between the strategies.

Comment: Ah, but that's the thing. `act_like_create_text :short` in your implementation means that this class can only generate short texts. If so, it will look better as `include WithShortText`. No magic :)

Comment: Yes, that is true, I meant that only if they can decide in advance, because the `condition` part in the question is not overly described.